# Add More than 200 Test Cases to Test Set Using Java Rally Rest API

Tags: java, rest, rally

Using Following Code I am able to add test cases in to newly created test set in RALLY.
But it add only first 200 test cases from the Test case list.

```
private static String createTestSet(RallyRestApi restApi, String TSName, String points)throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
  QueryRequest testcases = new QueryRequest("Test Case");
  testcases.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID", "Name", "Owner","Test Folder"));
  // All Test cases
  testcases.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("TestFolder.Name", "=","testFolder").and(new QueryFilter("Method", "=", "Manual")));

  testcases.setOrder("FormattedID ASC");
  QueryResponse queryResponse = restApi.query(testcases);
  JsonArray testCaseList = new JsonArray();
  if (queryResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("\nTotal results: %d", queryResponse.getTotalResultCount()));
    testCaseList=queryResponse.getResults().getAsJsonArray();
  }else{
    for (String err : queryResponse.getErrors()) {
      System.err.println("\t" + err);
    }
  }

  String ref = "null";
  System.out.println("Creating TestSet: "+TSName);
  try {
    if(!testCaseList.isJsonNull()){
      restApi.setApplicationName("PSN");
      JsonObject newTS = new JsonObject();
      newTS.addProperty("Name", TSName);
      newTS.addProperty("PlanEstimate", points);
      newTS.addProperty("Project", Project_ID);
      newTS.addProperty("Release", Release_ID);
      newTS.addProperty("Iteration", Iteration_ID);
      newTS.add("TestCases", testCaseList);
      CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testset",newTS);
      CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);
      ref = createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString();
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    //System.out.println("Exception Caught: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  return ref;
}
```

Although the Total Result count of Test case query filter is greater than 200, Test Set is getting created with only 200 Test case in it.

Comment: I haven't used the Rally API, but according to the documentation for [`QueryRequest`](https://docs.rallydev.com/javarestapi/com/rallydev/rest/request/QueryRequest.html) and [`QueryResponse`](https://docs.rallydev.com/javarestapi/com/rallydev/rest/response/QueryResponse.html), the results are paged, so is the default page limit just 200? What do you get when you call `QueryResponse.getPageSize`? Sorry I can't be of more help, hopefully this leads you down the right path. But if they are being paged, setting the page size to a larger number on the `QueryRequest` would fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

@Brian's comment above is correct.  By default [RallyRestApi.query](https://docs.rallydev.com/javarestapi/com/rallydev/rest/RallyRestApi.html#query%28com.rallydev.rest.request.QueryRequest%29)() will only return one page of data (with the default page size being 200).  [QueryResponse.getTotalResultCount](https://docs.rallydev.com/javarestapi/com/rallydev/rest/response/QueryResponse.html#getTotalResultCount%28%29)() will return the total number of records that matched on the server.  In order to get more than one page of data simply use [QueryRequest.setLimit](https://docs.rallydev.com/javarestapi/com/rallydev/rest/request/QueryRequest.html#setLimit%28int%29)() first to set an upper bound on the number of results you'd like returned.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. It's great help.